# Meaning of "resp." in Debian acpi command

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviations

I was recently reading the documentation for the Debian ACPI client's `acpi` command, and came across the following line that I was unsure of the meaning of.

```
$ acpi --help
Usage: acpi [OPTION]...
Shows information from the /proc filesystem, such as battery status or
thermal information.
[snip]
  -d, --directory     path to ACPI info (/sys/class resp. /proc/acpi)
[snip]
```

Each of those directories contains information pertinent to ACPI information (that is, about system components like the battery and fans), but are not identical and are structured directly. I am specifically confused as to the meaning of "resp." in this snippet. My first thought was that it stood for "respectively", but that would usually precede the list elements, and this flag only takes one argument, not two.

With this said, does anybody know what the author of the `acpi` command intended? I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a poor translation of the German *beziehungsweise*, meaning ["and" or "or"](http://transblawg.eu/2004/02/26/resp-and-other-non-existent-english-wordsnicht-existente-englische-worter/).